# Clicking within cursorSurroundingLines range highlights block of text

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use `"editor.cursorSurroundingLines": 10,` so when im navigating with keyboard (what i do 99% of the time) i have room to see below my cursor and i love this, however when i do use my mouse and i click within 10 lines of the top or bottom of screen, it scrolls (which is ok) but then decides to select/highlight all the text within those lines, which is dumb and annoying.
Anyone know any potential fixes to this?
(i just noticed it selects x amount based on the delay of me releasing the left mouse button)

Let me know if you need more info and sorry if this has been asked before, i could not find anything relevant to my issue.

Thanks

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQD3v.gif)

Comment: I am seeing this as well.  But it seems definitely related to slight mouse movement when I click.  So since the file is scrolling pursuant to the `"editor.cursorSurroundingLines"` setting it should select those lines.  Same as holding down the mouse button and moving the cursor should select lines.  It just seems very sensitive to the slightest mouse movement.  If you are very careful not to move the mouse when clicking in the autoscroll region no selection occurs.

Comment: Perhaps selection should be automatically turned off when clicking in the "autoscroll" region.  If you don't get any answer here I suggest you file an issue.  It is too sensitive to mouse movement, some of which is natural when you click a mouse button.

Comment: sorry it took me a bit to get back to you guys. appreciate the replies. i think i will submit this as a bug because its become extremely frustrating when on the go on the laptop.

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80997